# What's the simplest, most reliable way for me to track pageviews on my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pageviews

I've used Google Analytics for long enough to know that it doesn't work very well (issues on mobile phones and for people who've disabled Javascript, WAY too much of a lag time in updating). Currently, I'm just logging every request made of a page and updating a counter in my database, but I know that's inefficient and very crude (I'm not distinguishing between people and bots, I'm logging every page refresh as a new view).

What do you suggest for building a simple pageview counter? Another web analytics service? Writing my own counter that builds in rules like requiring that multiple pageviews from the same IP within 5 seconds of each other don't count? I've seen some people recommend parsing my production logs - I'm deploying on Heroku and don't have any idea where to start with that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We moved from GA to [GetClicky](http://getclicky.com/) some time ago and it's far far better.
They provide a non-JS tracking code as well. Give it a try.

Comment: Okay, I'm taking a look at it. Know of any Ruby gems or anything to let me easily access their API in my app?

Comment: Nope, but you can ask support@getclicky.com he usually replies very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Do what you want in a rack middleware. Inside you can put all code you want.